# Moving from activity to fragment-NullPointer exception in onCreateView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

My project crashes and shows following error on switching to fragment from activity.

```
08-12 20:00:56.835    1711-1711/com.facebooklogin E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at info.fastbadmainton2.slidingmenu.NewsFragment.onCreateView(NewsFragment.java:66)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It shows error in the statement-

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

Why it shows error in this statement?My app doesn't crashes if i remove this statement but my fragment becomes transparent such that activity is visible behind.Why my fragment becoms transparent?

Activity

```
public class NewsPopup extends FragmentActivity {
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newspopup);
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment newFragment = new NewsFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), NewsPopup2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView24);
        tv3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), NewsPopup3.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment   {
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter2 mAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;
     private String[] tabs = { "My Teams", "All Teams", "Trending" };
    public NewsFragment(){}
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);


        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
      actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        TextView tv=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);

        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setClass(myContext, NewsPopup.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        TextView tv1=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);

        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setClass(myContext, NewsPopup2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        TextView tv2=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView43);

        tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setClass(myContext, NewsPopup3.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search2:
                // recordVideo();
                //countClick++;
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(myContext, LeagueSelect2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    /*@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }*/
}
```

Comment: So why do you have the actionbar in the fragment? Shouldn't you simply add it to the activity and then use the activity to manage the fragments through the fragment manager?

Comment: actionBar = getActivity().getSupportActionBar();

Comment: @Eenvincible  actually this is not the main activity..this activity opens from another fragment and when i created a button to switch to another fragment from this activity its creating problem

Comment: Same fragment opens fine when i am opening it from another activity

Comment: My app doesn't crashes if i remove actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD); but my fragment becomes transparent such that activity is visible behind

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using support fragments. But your activity extends FragmentActivity. getActionBar() returns null on old devices, because they don't have any action bar. Make your activity extend ActionBarActivity from the appcompat library and then call

```
actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar();
```

Comment: i am not using actionbar code in activity..and i have other fragments also in my project in which same actionbar code runs fine